# CXF server - enable ssl null ciphers

Tags: web-services, ssl, cxf

As CXF server in internal trusted network, I want my server to communicate over SSL just with 
authentication and without encryption at all. 
For this, I'm trying to set tlsServerParameters in CXF conf file to except only null cipher 
like this:

```
<httpj:tlsServerParameters >
  <sec:keyManagers> <my keyManager> </sec:keyManagers>
  <sec:trustManagers> <my trustManager> </sec:trustManagers>

  <sec:cipherSuites>
    <sec:cipherSuite>SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5</sec:cipherSuite>
    <sec:cipherSuite> <some more ciphers> </sec:cipherSuite>
  </sec:cipherSuites>

  <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
  </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>

</httpj:tlsServerParameters>
```

When I connect with a client with null ciphers I keep getting
"SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Apparently this way doesn't work for NULL ciphers in 2.x.x version of CXF. http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-https-server-Allowing-null-ciphers-td5752465.html

Answer (score 0):

After days of researching I did it by extend SslContextFactory and override selectCipherSuites function.

```
<httpj:engine port=" ... ">
  <httpj:tlsServerParametersRef id=" ... " />

  <httpj:connector>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
      <property name="port" value=" ... " />
      <property name="maxIdleTime" value=" ... "/>
      <property name="keystore" value= " ... " />
      <property name="password" value= " ... " />
      <property name="keyPassword" value= " ... " />
      <property name="keystoreType" value= " ... " />

      <constructor-arg>
       <bean class=" ... MyContextFactoryForConnector">
         <property name="keyStore" value=" ... "/>
         <property name="keyStoreType" value=" ... "/>
         <property name="keyStorePassword" value=" ... "/>
         <property name="KeyManagerPassword" value=" ... "/>
       </bean>
     </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

```
public class MyContextFactoryForConnector extends SslContextFactory
{
    @Override
    public String[] selectCipherSuites(String[] enabledCipherSuites, String[] supportedCipherSuites)
    {
        return supportedCipherSuites;  // includes null ciphers
    }
}
```

Any more elegant way (that doesn't involves code) will be much better.

Thanks,